# Access content within cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, scrape

Is there are ANY way to access IFRAME content across different domains ?

I am a trying to load external pages into an iframe and scrape their info.
But get security errors in Chrome.

Comment: This is only likely to be possible in the browser if the site you're trying to scrape specifically allows Cross-origin requests. You can do this on a server without a problem.

Comment: If you are using php on the server have php cURL enabled, you can fetch the contents of the other pages from a "local" script. I bet for other server side languages there are similar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Since doing so would violate Cross Origin Resource Sharing and would, therefore, represent at a security vulnerability, the answer is not really.

If you're running your own server, you can use it as proxy.